# How to render a view from a view using a condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, view

I'm testing out RoR and am currently trying to figure out the functionality which allows users with a valid session to skip logging in.

The login button usually prompts you to a login page, whereas I want to make it so that people with a session skip it and immediately get redirected to the show view using a conditional statement. (Checks via current_user)
(If you need any other code just comment)

Here's the login view

```
<%= form_for :session, url: '/login' do |s| %>
<%= s.text_field :username, :placeholder => 'Username' %>
<%= s.password_field :password, :placeholder => 'Password' %>
<%= s.submit "Login" %>

<% if current_user %>
    <!-- What do i write here? -->
    <!-- Maybe I should put this in a controller? -->
    <% end %>

<% if flash[:notice] && current_user %>
    <div class="notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></div>
<% end %>
```

Here's the application controller containing the current_user function. (just in case)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
protect_from_forgery with: :exception

helper_method :current_user

 def current_user
   @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:id]) if session[:id]
 end
end
```

Comment: I suggest taking a step back and researching MVC principles (Google it). This redirect should be placed in the controller, not in the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what your SessionsController looks like, but you could add something like this:

```
class SessionsController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :check_current_user

  def check_current_user
    redirect_to :root, success: "You are already logged in." if current_user
  end
end
```

Then you can remove the `if current_user` statement in your login view. And for your login links you could write:

```
<%= link_to 'Login', new_session_path unless current_user %>
```

This way the login button only shows if `current_user` is nil.

Also, take a look at [Rails Tutorial Chapter 8: Basic Login](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/basic_login#cha-basic_login) for more information

Comment: No, how do I make it so that when a view is rendered, if current_user is not nil, it renders another view?

Comment: The view in your question looks like a login page, not a login partial. This is what my answer is based on. If you want to render a login partial, I suggest you go with Stephan L.'s approach

Answer (score 1):

Within your view you can render partials with the render method if you just want to show the login button to users that are not logged in:

```
<% unless current_user %>
  <%= render 'login_form' %>
<% end %>
```

Then you need to have a file named '_login_form' in your view directory:

```
<%= form_for :session, url: '/login' do |s| %>
<%= s.text_field :username, :placeholder => 'Username' %>
<%= s.password_field :password, :placeholder => 'Password' %>
<%= s.submit "Login" %>
```